# Assign new string value if value is in typescript array

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

How do you assign a new value to a typed string in Typescript if you're not sure if that new value exists in the array of valid string types? E.g.

```
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'] as const;
type Fruit = typeof fruits[number];

export default function () {
  let selectedFruit: Fruit = 'apple';

  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  const fruitParam = url.searchParams.get('fruit'); // type is string | null

  if (fruits.some((fruit) => fruitParam === fruit)) {
    selectedFruit = fruitParam; // Typescript error: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type '"apple" | "banana" | "orange"'
  }

  return selectedFruit;
}
```

Shouldn't the `fruits.some((fruit) => fruitParam === fruit))` check ensure that the `fruitParam` is indeed a valid fruit type? Is the TS compiler not able to infer from that check? I've also tried `fruits.includes(fruit)` and others without any luck. Of course, explicitly listing the types `fruitParam === 'apple' || fruitParam === 'banana' || fruitParam === 'orange'` *does* work, but isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a deal with types compatibility.
`selectedFruit` can be one of `'apple', 'banana', 'orange'`
`randomFruit` in your case i just a string

So, union type can't be extended by `string`, **but** `string` type can be extended by `'apple', 'banana', 'orange'`.

Hence, if you write:

```js
  let randomFruit = getRandomFruit();

  if (fruits.some((fruit) => randomFruit === fruit)) {
    randomFruit = selectedFruit // no error
    selectedFruit = randomFruit; // Typescript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"apple" | "banana" | "orange"'
  }
```

it will work.

So, let's go back to your problem.

To make it clearer, let's add `as const` to `basket`

```js
const basket = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lychee', 'pear', 'grapefruit'] as const;
```

Now, you have similar but more understandable error message:

```
Type '"apple" | "banana" | "orange" | "lychee" | "pear" | "grapefruit"' is not assignable to type '"apple" | "banana" | "orange"'
```

To make it work, you should define all possible fruits in `fruits` array.
Your basket shoul allow only fruits that are exists in `fruits` array - for me it does make sense.

Example:

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lychee', 'pear', 'grapefruit'] as const;
type Fruit = typeof fruits[number];

const basket = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'] as const;

const getRandomFruit = () => basket[Math.floor(Math.random() * basket.length)];

export default function () {
  let selectedFruit: Fruit = 'apple';

  const randomFruit = getRandomFruit();

  if (fruits.some((fruit) => randomFruit === fruit)) {
    selectedFruit = randomFruit; // no error
  }

  return selectedFruit;
}
```

**Update**

Here you have a solution with typeguard:

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'] as const;
type Fruit = typeof fruits[number];

/**
 * You should yo use typeguard instead of simple condition
 */
const isAllowedFruit = (fruit: string | null): fruit is Fruit => typeof fruit === 'string' ? fruits.includes(fruit as Fruit) : false

export default function () {
        let selectedFruit: Fruit = 'apple';

        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        const fruitParam = url.searchParams.get('fruit'); // type is string | null

        if (isAllowedFruit(fruitParam)) {
                selectedFruit = fruitParam; // ok
        }

        return selectedFruit;
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) you can read more about typeguards

Comment: Ah, thanks @captain-yossarian for the thoughtful answer. This absolutely answers my original question, but I'm realizing maybe I wasn't specific enough to my use-case. I've updated to more closely illustrate the issue I'm having. Essentially, I don't know what the incoming string is going to be, as I'm pulling it from the query params (so it's type is `string` | `null`), but I still need to check whether it satisfies the `type Fruit`.

Comment: @caption-yossarian great thank you! That answers my question!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a total nice solution but a better solution then check each field manual.
You can iterate in a forEach and assign it then to `selectedFruit`

```
fruits.forEach((item) => {
    if (item === randomFruit) {
        selectedFruit = randomFruit;
    }
});
```

instead of

```
if (fruits.some((fruit) => randomFruit === fruit)) {
    selectedFruit = randomFruit; // Typescript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"apple" | "banana" | "orange"'
}
```